# How does google collect tweets?

Tags: twitter, search-engine, real-time

Google displays tweets in their [real time service](http://www.google.co.uk/realtime?hl=en&tab=wY). I'm just wondering how they collect these?

Answer (score 2):

Google has [access](http://techcrunch.com/2009/10/21/that-didnt-take-long-twitter-is-coming-to-google/) to Twitter's firehose of tweets. It is a [realtime stream](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/firehose) of all public tweets published through Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be using the Twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure google has access to the twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

The Google search also includes the "Search in Twitter". Keywords are also searched under twitter, and the results are posted. I guess..